# Cannot search Elastic Search with string containing "/0"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search to search for my `ID`. My `ID` somehow looks like `21.11101/0000-0000-9B71-2`. However, when I use it in my ES, it will throw an error saying that:

> Failed to parse query [21.11101/0000-0000-9B71-2]"
>
> Encountered: EOF after : \"/0000-0000-9B71-2\"

I think this happens because ES thinks that `/0` is an `EOF` character. **How to tell ES to treat my search query as a normal text?** Here is my query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "21.11101/0000-0000-9B71-2"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `_mapping`:

```
"PID": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use Prefix Query, so basically, my query will look like this:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "ID" : "21.11101/00"
    }
  }
}
```

But that query returns 0 hit. I guess because of the error is above. So, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down a little bit: what your mapping says is:

- `"PID": { "type": "text", ...` which means the content of `PID` field will be text with default analyzer, which `standard`. It will tokenize your input text by white-spaces and some word-delimiters, like `-`(hyphen), `/`(forward slash) and some other.
- `... "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 } }` will prompt ES to keep additional version of your `PID` field as a keyword, which will be accessible via alias `PID.keyword`. The important limitation of [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/multi-fields.html) is that you can't perform search against it. You can only make sorting and aggregation.

Taking that into account my suggestion is as simple as specifying non-standard analyzer which won't tokenize input text (it is `keyword` analyzer):

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_pids -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "pid": {
      "properties": {
        "PID": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

If you won't use the sorting / aggregation by your `PID.keyword` field - feel free to drop the `fields` section as well.

Hope it helps :)